# How can we transcode live rtmp stream to live hls stream using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I am trying to convert a live rtmp stream to hls stream on real time.

I got some idea after reading

http://sonnati.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/ffmpeg-%E2%80%93-the-swiss-army-knife-of-internet-streaming-%E2%80%93-part-iv/

i am able to convert the live rtmp stream to hls but not at run time. when i run the command and test for any hsl files (.m3u8 and .ts) i am not able to see but when i interrupt the command and check there i get the hls files as required.

I searched on google for solution but not able to get proper answer.

Answer (score 90):

This is a short guide for HLS streaming with any input file or stream:

I am following user1390208's approach, so I use FFMPEG only to produce the rtmp stream which my server then receives to provide HLS. Instead of Unreal/Wowza/Adobe, I use the free server nginx with the rtmp module, which is quite easy to setup. This is how I do it in short: `Any input file or stream -> ffmpeg -> rtmp -> nginx server ->  HLS -> Client` or more detailed:

input video file or stream (http, rtmp, whatever) --> ffmpeg transcodes live to x.264 + aac, outputs to rtmp --> nginx takes the rtmp and serves a HLS to the user (client).
So on the client side you can use VLC or whatever and connect to the .m3u8 file which is provided by nginx.

- I followed [this](http://pkula.blogspot.de/2013/06/live-video-stream-from-raspberry-pi.html) setup guide for nginx.
- [This](http://pastebin.com/8Wf2tpaQ) is my nginx config file.
- This is how I use ffmpeg to transcode my input file to rtmp:

  ```
  ffmpeg -re -i mydirectory/myfile.mkv -c:v libx264 -b:v 5M -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a:0 libfdk_aac -b:a:0 480k -f flv rtmp://localhost:12345/hls/mystream;
  ```

  (the .mkv is 1080p with 5.1 sound, depending on your input, you should use lower bitrates!)

Where do you get the rtmp stream from?

- A file? Then you can use exactly my approach.
- Any server X with a stream Y? Then you have to change the ffmpeg command to:

  ```
  ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://theServerX/yourStreamY -c:v libx264 -b:v 5M -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a:0 libfdk_aac -b:a:0 480k -f flv rtmp://localhost:12345/hls/mystream;
  ```

  or if your rtmp stream is already h.264/aac encoded, you could try to use the `copy` option in ffmpeg to stream the content directly to nginx.

As you see in my nginx config file:

- My rtmp server has an "application" called "hls". That's the part that describes where nginx listens to ffmpeg's rtmp stream and that's why ffmpeg streams to `rtmp://localhost:12345/hls/mystream;`
- My http server has the `location /hls`. This means in VLC I can connect to `http://myServer:80/hls/mystream.m3u8` to access the HLS stream.

Is everything clear? Happy streaming!

Comment: This is a very helpful answer.

Comment: Great answer ! Just what I needed.

Comment: Can I use RTSP/RTP for input stream in nginx?!

Comment: I don't understand how you connect the `location /hls` to the `application hls` and get the stream out of /hls/mystream.m3u8 (at least it doesn't work for me that easy).

Comment: @dCSeven what doesn't work for you? Have you tried with my exact nginx config file and connect to it in VLC via URL mentioned above?

Comment: Does this method make the HLS stream adapt bitrate/quality depending on the client/viewer's connection? Or would I need to have multiple ffmpeg calls and hls applications to serve that?

Comment: @ROODAY no, but you can make it work using hls_variant tags, see https://licson.net/post/setting-up-adaptive-streaming-with-nginx/

Answer (score 30):

Try this RTMP to HLS command line settings:

```
ffmpeg -v verbose -i rtmp://<host>:<port>/<stream> -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -crf 18 -profile:v baseline -maxrate 400k -bufsize 1835k -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags -global_header -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -start_number 1 <pathToFolderYouWantTo>/<streamName>.m3u8
```

There might be some delay in the HLS feed. However, it'll work.

Comment: Great simple answer! Any way to reduce the latency?

Answer (score 3):

As an update to this question, I've managed to complete the live transcoding from RTMP to HLS without the use of ffmpeg, how?

Well just by using the exact same nginx config file shared by user3069376 and being very careful about the paths that you are generating the .m3uh manifesto, the hls option within the RTMP module should take care of it.

As for video player the Video.Js worked like a charm o

Comment: can you please elaborate more or share a conf file ?

Comment: as I know, nginx use FFMPEG behind the scenes to transcode.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the `RTMP` live stream ready and playing as HLS then you can simply add `.m3u8` after the stream name and make `RTMP` link to `http`. For example you have `RTMP` link like this:

> `rtmp://XY.Y.ZX.Z/hls/chid`

You have to just make the url like this:

> `http://XY.Y.ZX.Z/hls/chid.m3u8`

and it will play smoothly in iOS. I have tried following code and it is working fine.

```
func setPlayer()
{
    // RTMP URL rtmp://XY.Y.ZX.Z/hls/chid be transcripted like this http://XY.Y.ZX.Z/hls/chid.m3u8 it will play normally.

    let videoURL = URL(string: "http://XY.Y.ZX.Z/hls/chid.m3u8")

    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL!)
    let adID = AVMetadataItem.identifier(forKey: "X-TITLE", keySpace: .hlsDateRange)
    let metadataCollector = AVPlayerItemMetadataCollector(identifiers: [adID!.rawValue], classifyingLabels: nil)
    //metadataCollector.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    playerItem.add(metadataCollector)


    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    self.player = player
    player.play()
}
```

But it will be slow and laggy because of the high resolution video stream upload. If you make the resolution to low when uploading the video stream, it will work smooth in low bandwidth network as well.

> Please note: It is not by FFMPEG as we have already RTMP running by
>   FFMPEG so I did like this.