# Sending H.264 live stream to Nginx and publish as HLS to embed into website

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, html5-video, h.264, http-live-streaming

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658216/how-can-we-transcode-live-rtmp-stream-to-live-hls-stream-using-ffmpeg/35792710#35792710) post I am trying to display an H.264 live stream from an ip camera (AXIS M1145-L + CamStreamer plugin) on a webpage without using any external browser plugins (only pure HTML5) and for desktop.

As I`ve read there it is possible to do it with video.js and HLS, so this is what I have tried:

```
Stream from camera (push to rtmp with CamStreamer) --> to nginx (rtmp module) --> 
nginx serves HLS --> display with video.js and videojs-hls plugin in browser
```

While watching the stream within VLC using it`s hls URL (http://192.168.1.105:8080/hls/movie.m3u8) I do not have any problems or lags but I can not get it to work in the browser with video.js.

It always reports me **invalid media**.

- stream in vlc + codec info:
  http://s8.postimg.org/vb63fgfwh/codec.png
- my nginx config: http://pastebin.com/9GuAMuBx
- html source code: http://pastebin.com/QGmEamjT
- output in chrome: http://s8.postimg.org/dwlv76irl/error_html.png

The original stream is pushed to: *rtmp://192.168.1.105:1935/hls/movie*

*192.168.1.105* is the machine where nginx is running.

The Hls stream then is accesible on http://192.168.1.105:8080/hls/movie.m3u8

What I totally want to avoid is the need of re-encoding the video as the machine on where it will run later does not have the power to do it and it will be a full hd stream too. This is why I have abandoned FFmpeg (needed to re-encode Mp4 for Live-Streaming). Also the machine will not have continous internet access, so online transcoding also isn`t possible.

Please help. Thank you !

Comment: Hi Thomas, How you are getting 192.168.1.105:8080/hls/movie.m3u8. I followed the steps given [here](https://northwoodsdigital.com/how-to-install-nginx-rtmp-server-hls-on-ubuntu-16-04-easy/) but getting 404 error.Please guide me to get this work.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the requirement of not reencoding on a weaker machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it.

Using hls.js library (https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js) standalone **without** video.js did the trick. The video is now playing fine in Chrome/Opera on Windows 7. Did not yet try it with others.

So I guess it`s a player/codec dependend problem of video.js.

The html page with the player needs to be on a server (NOT local filesystem!) otherwise browser safety restrictions will come in place which prevents the video from playing. Noticed that while trying from a local html page in browser while hls.js demo worked with same stream.

Thank you for your tips !

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue trying to get a Video.js player (with the HLS contrib module) to load an HLS stream in PC/Chrome. The player would display "The media could not be loaded... because the format is not supported."

I later found it played fine in Mac/Safari and PC/MS Edge browsers.

Full browser support for HLS is still fairly lacking.
https://www.jwplayer.com/html5/#adaptive-streaming

I had success with Bitmovin's player Bitdash and realized it was a browser issue (not stream or nginx issue).

Comment: @Thomas233 - Does the video stream work on the page in Mac/Safari or PC/MS Edge?